# Как сделать TreeViewItem с кнопками?

Tags: c#, wpf

**Добавлено из комментария**.

```
<TreeView Height="500" Name="tvGroups" AllowDrop="True">
  <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <TreeViewItem Name="parent1" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Header=">">
    <TreeViewItem Header="A">
      <TreeViewItem Header="Item 1"></TreeViewItem>
      <TreeViewItem Header="Item 2"></TreeViewItem>
    </TreeViewItem>
      <TreeViewItem Header="B">
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item 1"></TreeViewItem>
      </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeViewItem>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="20" Content="Add"/>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="20" Content="Delete"/>
  </DockPanel>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Не забывайте принимать ответы на вопросы, которые задаёте.

Comment: Как принимать?

Comment: Чтобы принять ответ, который вас устроил, нужно нажать на галочку слвева от ответа (под кулачком вниз).

Answer (score 2):

В книге Мэтью Макдоналда WPF 4 C# есть в какой-то из глав про ListBox TreeViewItem, про создание кнопок в шаблоне, просто к каждой строке привязываете к свойству tag, например, номер строки и при нажатии кнопки строки Х уже можно отталкиваться дальше и предпринимать какие-то действия....

Answer (score 1):

Нужно объявить и подключить шаблон для TreeViewItem, в котором будут кнопки.

Comment: А пример можно как сделать такой шаблон? 

Я пока сделал так но выделение TreeViewItem не работает. Как сделать чтобы и выделение работало?

Comment: Перенесено в вопрос.

Comment: примеры посмотрите здесь
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17025/Custom-TreeView-Layout-in-WPF

Answer (score 1):

View:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel></local:ViewModel>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <Button Foreground="Red" Content="{Binding Name}"></Button>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<TreeItemViewModel> MyItems { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        MyItems = new ObservableCollection<TreeItemViewModel>();

        MyItems.Add(new TreeItemViewModel()
        {
            Name = "lvl1"
        });
        MyItems.Add(new TreeItemViewModel()
        {
            Name = "lvl1",
            Children =new ObservableCollection<TreeItemViewModel>() {new TreeItemViewModel() { Name = "lvl2" } }
        });
        MyItems.Add(new TreeItemViewModel()
        {
            Name = "lvl1"
        });
    }
}

public class TreeItemViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<TreeItemViewModel> Children { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]